# ora-06413 connection not open in visual studio 2010 (Server Explorer)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

I've been trying to open a connection to my Oracle database (x86) in visual studio 2010 (x64) from a Server Explorer tool.

I get this error :

> ora-06413 connection not open

The strange thing is that I can connect to the database from my C# code instead of using Server Explorer Tool.
What Kind of problem could it be ?

Answer (score 2):

try to change the visual studio directory from `C:\Program Files (x86)` to `C:\VS` or anything else without "(" or ")".